# PhoneGap / Android WebView throws "Unknown chromium error: 0"

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, chromium

I'm currently developing a project using PhoneGap and I need to do an ajax request to my local webserver which has already:

PHP code

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Anyway, when I do an ajax request with jQuery on Android I get this error (in adb logcat):

```
D/chromium(23078): Unknown chromium error: 0
```

The Javascript code is:

```
$.ajax({url:"http://192.168.1.219/works/privati/folder/api.php/getlastmaginfo",dataType:"json",success:function(data)
{
    console.log("Finished loading by ajax");
    console.log(data);
}});
```

In Ripple Emulator works as expected, in Android nope.

Any suggestion? Thank you for the help!

**UPDATE 2013-08-21:**

After some researches I came at the conclusion that $.ajax won't work with PhoneGap (don't know why, maybe a bug?).
We must use $.get instead, but when I do a request with $.get I get `Unknown chromium error: -6`
I also read [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535) that the problem is due to an Android's bug with the WebView URL mechanism.

I'll continue my research until I find a good and working solution

**UPDATE 2013-08-21 (2):**
Not even using this works...

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

fileTransfer.download(
    "http://192.168.1.219/works/privati/qlipmag/api.php/getlastmaginfo",
    "json.json",
    function(entry) {
        console.log("OKAY");

    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

Error is at `new FileTransfer();` => `Uncaught ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined`

**UPDATE 2013-08-22:**

It doens't work even by loading an external image:

`<img src="http://externalhost.com/image.jpg"/>`

Same error.

In android manifest file I already setted permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I don't really know from where comes the problem...

**UPDATE 2013-08-27:**
I tried the same code on PhoneGap for iPhone (in iPhone Emulator) and the ajax request was successfull when I used an external website. Using an external website also on android doesn't get the same result.
Same error.

Anybody can see why? Access origin are setted fine...

Comment: Same problem here...but i'm using backbone and getting data setting "url" in a Collection.

Comment: thumbs up buddy, methodical research and documentation is impressive,plus you just solved my problem so well done.

Comment: This is why you should read the documentation :)

Comment: Make sure to "answer" your question, and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE 2013-08-27 (after 1 hour)**

**ISSUE SOLVED**

Actually PhoneGap doesn't allows ajax request to ip addresses, it only allows requests to whitelisted (in config.xml) domains.
I used the production server (with domain) to test and it worked.

Thank you anyway guys. I hope this can help

Comment: hi, i have two app version, identical, one work the other throw this error. only difference phonegap version: probably this ip address limitation was fixed after  phonegap 3.1.0

Comment: @Denys Vitali I am also facing same issue, can I add the IP address in domain name.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify on this in case someone stumbles upon it like I did, $.ajax does work with PhoneGap/Cordova for sure - but as you found .. the domain must be whitelisted.

Answer (score 1):

As of Cordova 4 and above having only `<access origin="*" />` within the config.xml doesn't work. You need to use the cordova-plugin-whitelist.

Once the plugin is installed you can use the following code within the config.xml to accomplish the same:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Please note that in general it's no good practise to use the "*" als wildcard. Rather define the protocols and addresses specifically.

For more information about how to use the cordova-plugin-whitelist please visit https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10356844)

Comment: Yes, you're right...sorry quite new here. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling cache

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    //your code
});
```

This error message is really vacuous. It mostly means that your app cannot find the resource on the file system. So try disabling the cache, so it will always load the resource from the server.

Comment: Nothing, not a cache problem, same error:
`D/chromium( 3228): Unknown chromium error: 0`