# WebView throws “Unknown chromium error: 0”

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I have an application that is based on `Cordova` `3.5.0` which we are now upgrading to version `5.2.0`. I am encountering the following exception when trying to load the html/javascript sources from a remote server:

```
Unknown chromium error: 0
```

From what I have read I understand that this is caused by location being loaded into the webview not being in the `Cordova` whitelist. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325393/phonegap-android-webview-throws-unknown-chromium-error-0) for example pertains to this error message, but the answers given are from the perspective of how to configure `Cordova`. What I am wanting to know is where in the java source this functionality is implemented. So I am looking specifically for an answer from the perspective of the `Java` source, not from the perspective of `Cordova`. (ie. saying "add this to your config.xml" is not the answer I am looking for).

This error message is a particularly unhelpful one and it would be useful to know what configuration of the `Android` `Webview` causes this and how it this restriction can be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should look at these files:

- [SystemWebViewClient.java](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/4bf705a3d39b34400388265381a9975b246e3779/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewClient.java#L321)
- [CordovaWebViewImpl.java](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/4bf705a3d39b34400388265381a9975b246e3779/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewImpl.java#L218)
- [Whitelist.java](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/4bf705a3d39b34400388265381a9975b246e3779/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/Whitelist.java)

This is a piece of code from the method `shouldInterceptRequest` from the `SystemWebViewClient` class:

```
        // Check the against the whitelist and lock out access to the WebView directory
        // Changing this will cause problems for your application
        if (!parentEngine.pluginManager.shouldAllowRequest(url)) {
            LOG.w(TAG, "URL blocked by whitelist: " + url);
            // Results in a 404.
            return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "UTF-8", null);
        }
```