# Cordova / Android web view Ajax request: 'unknown chromium error'

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

I have just upgraded from Cordova v3.4 to latest 6.1.1. My whole android app is working just fine apart from ALL jquery Ajax calls here is a sample one:

```
var baseUrl = 'http://gazetkisklepowe.pl';

$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl+"/api/get/favourites",
    data: {
        user_uuid: device.uuid
    }
}).done(function(data) {

}).fail(function() {
    alert('Error connecting. (100) '+baseUrl+"/api/get/favourites");
    return null;
});
```

I have read this article: [PhoneGap / Android WebView throws "Unknown chromium error: 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325393/phonegap-android-webview-throws-unknown-chromium-error-0) but I haven't found a solution for me.

The message in the LogCat just displays: "unknown chromium error: 0"

My config.xml contains:

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

SN: I would like just to inform that previously on Cordova v3.4 all Ajax requests worked just fine and there have not been any changes in the code since then.

**UPDATE 10am 5/04/2016**

I have added whitelist plugin and `<allow-navigation href="data:*" />` to the config.xml, now I get:

```
object has no method 'error' at file ///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js:24
```

Line 24 in that js file is: console.error(msg); so from some reason console is not fully defined.

**UPDATE 2pm 05/04/2016**

I have created new cordova app in separate folder and copied my files over, that done the trick and have fixed everything.